# C++ nested templates

Tags: c++, visual-c++-2010

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Strange VC++ compile error, C2244](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1484885/strange-vc-compile-error-c2244)

I have the following C++ code with a template struct and a template member function of it. The template function uses a template parameter in its declaration. The code doesn't compile.

```
template<typename MyType>
struct Network
{
    template<typename MyOtherType>
    void Do_Stuff(char param[MyOtherType::size]);
};

template<typename MyType>
template<typename MyOtherType>
void Network<MyType>::Do_Stuff(char param[MyOtherType::size])
{
};

struct Array_Size
{
    static const int size;
};

const int Array_Size::size=3;

int main()
{
}
```

Visual Studio 2010 generates the following error:

```
error C2244: 'Network<MyType>::Do_Stuff' : unable to match function definition to an existing declaration
    definition
    'void Network<MyType>::Do_Stuff(char [MyOtherType::size])'
    existing declarations
    'void Network<MyType>::Do_Stuff(char [MyOtherType::size])'
```

I don't understand why the compiler does not find a match even though the definition and declaration are identical.

Comment: Can you show where you actually use the template? That code compiles fine on g++.

Comment: @Nick Maybe a VS2010 issue? Worked for me on g++ as well.

Comment: I guess I was right then that it's a VS issue. No reason for this not to compile (at least from this code given).

Comment: I added the tag `visual-c++-2010`, since this seems to be compiler-dependent. I hope this is ok ;)

Comment: Compiles under VS2012 as well. Anyway, what is the intention in the parameter `char param[MyOtherType::size]`. What is the difference between that and `char *param`?

Comment: @Csq: There is no difference.  Perhaps he should use an array reference (which enforces the bound).

Comment: I'd be trying what Ben recommends: in case you didn't follow, something like `void Do_Stuff(char (&param)[MyOtherType::size]);`

Comment: Did you try an inline implementation, and does it make any difference? Ah, and how's that method actually instantiated (you might need a template specifier for the parameter)

Comment: It is good to know that the code compiles under g++ and VS2012. Looks like it is a VS2010 issue. Thanks to those who answered my question.