# boost::bind for a non-static member function in a template class

Tags: c++, templates, boost, stl, bind

```
template<typename T> class testClass{
    public:
    bool compare(const int& a, const int& b){
        T x;
        ....
    }
    void sort(){
        std::sort( data.begin() ,
                data.end() ,
                boost::bind<bool>(
                &testClass<T>::compare,
                this, _1 , _2 ) );
    }
    std::vector<int> data;
}
```

I have a template-d class with a non-static member function intended as comparator for `std::sort`. The comparator depends on the `typename T` parameter. As it has an implicit `this` pointer I try to `boost::bind` the pointer `this` to it.

Yet neither `boost::bind<bool>(.......)` nor `boost::bind(....)` would compile.

The example above fails on MSVC 2008 (as I'm on a non-English environment I'm not sure about the exact message in English, but probably complaining about either prototypes could make all necessary conversions of arguments feasible.)

Comment: please post the error message, use an online compiler to get the English message if necessary

Comment: And post the code you tried, `(.....)` isn't helpful.

Comment: [this](http://liveworkspace.org/code/4CeG4e$0) compiles, though I don't know if its the same as your code.

Comment: Well thanks. Turns out to be an issue similar to [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1484885/strange-vc-compile-error-c2244) in another member function related. I moved parts of code from `class.cpp` to `class.hpp` and now it works.

Comment: @Phoeagon please post an answer to your question if you solved it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after quite some digging... The problem indeed does not lie in the snippet presented above.

Turns out to be an issue similar to ([Strange VC++ compile error, C2244](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1484885/strange-vc-compile-error-c2244)) in another member function related. A function called in `compare` happened to be a template function that failed to compile exactly like the one in the above question. I didn't notice THAT error at first.

I moved parts of code from `class.cpp` to `class.hpp` and now it works.

A stupid MSVC bug, and a stupid mistake I made.